# Huge static data in SQLite in iOS - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite, static

I have huge data which is static. I need to save it within the application and retrive it from database and use the data in the application. The data doesnt going to change, as I thought of using XML since the data is huge it will increase the app size and hence the idea of using SQLite. Is there any tutorial how to use SQLite for static data in iOS. Or is there anything else other than SQLite? Please help. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Sounds like you should at least consider compressing your data. If your application is too big, it can't be downloaded over the cell network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any static data you must use sqlite data base and creat table which you want 
Here are some links for using sqlite in iPhone

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iPhone_Application

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

hope this helps you in working

Answer (score 1):

Core Data with SQLite will be a good choise for you.

But if you are going to store really big files there, you'll better not store themselves in the database, but URL's to them instead, while storing files in the filesystem.

You can read about BLOBs("Binary Large OBjects") and Core Data in Apple Core Data Programming Guide.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html

Comment: I m not going to store files, just static text. I think sqlite will do. Suggest please.

Comment: What's the average size of your text files will be?

Comment: 1330 poems of two lines and each of its explanation in both english and local language.

Comment: I think,that storing so tiny files in SQL would be OK.

Comment: As Marcus Zarra says,little files are less than 100K and you should store them in you sqlite

Comment: You can't save static data on CD. You sholdn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out FMDB, an iOS compatible Objective C wrapper for sqlite3.

https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial given by `Jani` are nice and you can start with it. But after getting basic idea of SQLite you can check the [objective - c wrapper of SQLite c library (FMDB)](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the data from a webservice? Surely it cant be that big if you are manually creating data. I would go with CoreData over a SQLite wrapper. Working with objects is much more straight forward verses running queries and trying to work with the data.

It is just a much more robust solution (IMO), noting the fact that you dont have to worry about supporting a 3rd party framework for your data (not that there arent really excellent ones).

Think about the future of your application as well when making these decisions, it will save you a lot of headache in the long run.

Check out this CoreData document.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075

Comment: Thanks. Let me check out and decide what goes good with me.. :)